# tensorflow serving : segmentation fault running inception_saved_model

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I followed the steps given [here](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_inception). But while running following command

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.runfiles/tf_serving/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model
```

I am getting "Segmentation fault". i could trace it to following line in tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.py file:

```
serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='tf_example')
```

Can some one pls help me here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had to rebuild the container from scratch again. But after that build started failing. Made following changes to finally make it work:

1. changed gcc version to 4.9
2. changed bazel version to 0.4.5
3. applied patch mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/354#issuecomment-287592905)
4. build command (I am running on mac with 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5 + 8 GB RAM) :  `bazel build -c opt --jobs 50 --local_resources 2048,0.5,1.0 tensorflow_serving/...`